# JQuery slideToggle shoult slideUp all the other shown container

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

That's what sould happen:

I click on one of the menue items, the text container should slide down when i klick on an other the already opened container slide up and the clickt container slide down.
but how i tried "siblings" but that doesnt worked the way i want it to.

and that's how far i already am

```
<style>

 .read_more, .read_it, .read_that, .read_this{
  color: black;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight:bold;
  }

 .inhalt, .inhalt_it, .inhalt_this, .inhalt_that{
  display:none;
  }
 li{
  display: inline;
  list-style-type: none;
  }


</style>
</head>

<body>

<a class="read_more">BTN 1</a>
<div class="inhalt">
 text 1
</div>

<ul>
<li class="read_it">BTN 2</a></li>
<li class="read_that">BTN 3</a></li>
<li class="read_this">BTN 4</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="inhalt_it">
 text 2
</div>
<div class="inhalt_that">
 text 3
</div>
<div class="inhalt_this">
 text 4
</div>


<script>
     $('.read_more').click(function() {
       $(this).nextAll('div.inhalt:first').slideToggle("slow").siblings('div.inhalt_it, div.inhalt_that, div.inhalt_this').slideUp('slow').css('background', '#F00F');

     });

     $('li.read_it').click(function(){
      $(this).nextAll('div.inhalt_it:first').slideToggle("slow").siblings('div.inhalt, div.inhalt_that, div.inhalt_this').slideUp('slow').css('background', 'Yellow');

     });

     $('li.read_this').click(function(){
      $(this).nextAll('div.inhalt_this:first').slideToggle("slow").siblings('div.inhalt, div.inhalt_it, div.inhalt_that').slideUp('slow').css('background', 'Blue');


     });

     $('li.read_that').click(function(){
      $(this).nextAll('div.inhalt_that:first').slideToggle("slow").siblings('div.inhalt, div.inhalt_it, div.inhalt_that, div.inhalt_this').slideUp('slow').css('background', 'Red');



     });
</script>
```

I tryed to to fixed the order problem like this

```
        <script>
    //
        $('.read_it').click(function(){
                $(this).siblings('div.inhalt, div.inhalt_prozesse, div.inhalt_recht').slideUp('slow', function(){
                    $(this).nextAll('div.inhalt_it:first').slideToggle("slow").css('background', 'Yellow');
                });
    //
             </script>
```

How can I  achieve that?!?
I already say thanks for any help.....

I made it may be not in the most ellegent way but it works....
 if any one could tell me how it can be improved i'll be very thank full...

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script> 

<style>
    .inhalt, .inhalt1, .inhalt2, .inhalt3{
        display: none;
        }

        .read1, .inhalt_1, .inhalt_2, .inhalt_3{
        color: black;
        font-size: 20px;
        font-weight:bold;
        }

        ul{
            display: inline;
            list-style-type: none;
            }
            li{
                display: inline;
            }


</style>

</head>

<body>

<a class="read1">BTN1</a>
    <div class="inhalt">
        content.<br />
    </div>
    <br />

<a class="inhalt_1">BTN2</a>
<a class="inhalt_2">BTN3</a>
<a class="inhalt_3">BTN4</a>



    <div class="inhalt1">
        Some content1.<br />
    </div>

    <div class="inhalt2">
        Some content2.<br /><br />
    </div>

    <div class="inhalt3">
        Some content3.<br />
    </div>
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

// BTN 1 begin
    $('.read1').click(function(){
        if ($('div.inhalt1').css('display') == 'block'){
            $('div.inhalt1').slideUp('slow', (function(){
                $('div.inhalt').slideToggle('slow')
            }))
            }
            else if($('div.inhalt2').css('display') == 'block'){
                $('div.inhalt2').slideUp('slow', (function(){
                    $('div.inhalt').slideToggle('slow')
                }))
            }
            else if($('div.inhalt3').css('display') == 'block'){
                $('div.inhalt3').slideUp('slow', (function(){
                    $('div.inhalt').slideToggle('slow')
                }))
            }
            else{
                $(this).nextAll('div.inhalt:first').slideToggle('slow');
                }
                });
// BTN 1 end        

// BTN 2 begin      
        $('.inhalt_1').click(function(){
            if ($('div.inhalt').css('display') == 'block'){
                $('div.inhalt').slideUp('slow', (function(){
                    $('div.inhalt1').slideToggle('slow')
                    }))
                }
                else if($('div.inhalt2').css('display') == 'block'){
                    $('div.inhalt2').slideUp('slow', (function(){
                        $('div.inhalt1').slideToggle('slow')
                        }))
                }
                else if($('div.inhalt3').css('display') == 'block'){
                    $('div.inhalt3').slideUp('slow', (function(){
                        $('div.inhalt1').slideToggle('slow')
                }))
                }
                else{
                    $(this).nextAll('div.inhalt1:nth(0)').slideToggle('slow');
                    }
                    });
// BTN 2 end

// BTN 3 begin

    $('.inhalt_2').click(function(){
        if ($('div.inhalt').css('display') == 'block'){
                $('div.inhalt').slideUp('slow', (function(){
                    $('div.inhalt2').slideToggle('slow')
                    }))
                }
                else if($('div.inhalt1').css('display') == 'block'){
                    $('div.inhalt1').slideUp('slow', (function(){
                        $('div.inhalt2').slideToggle('slow')
                        }))
                }
                else if($('div.inhalt3').css('display') == 'block'){
                    $('div.inhalt3').slideUp('slow', (function(){
                        $('div.inhalt2').slideToggle('slow')
                }))
                }
                else {
                    $(this).nextAll('div.inhalt2:first').slideToggle('slow');
                    }
                    })

// BTN 3 end

// BTN 4 begin

$('.inhalt_3').click(function(){
        if ($('div.inhalt').css('display') == 'block'){
                $('div.inhalt').slideUp('slow', (function(){
                    $('div.inhalt3').slideToggle('slow')
                    }))
                }
                else if($('div.inhalt1').css('display') == 'block'){
                    $('div.inhalt1').slideUp('slow', (function(){
                        $('div.inhalt3').slideToggle('slow')
                        }))
                }
                else if($('div.inhalt2').css('display') == 'block'){
                    $('div.inhalt2').slideUp('slow', (function(){
                        $('div.inhalt3').slideToggle('slow')
                }))
                }
                else {
                    $(this).nextAll('div.inhalt3:first').slideToggle('slow');
                    }
                    })


// BTN 4 end


});

</script>
```

Comment: I created a jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/jn2Yb/. Is this how the BTN's should look? If no, how should they look and what should they do exactly?

Comment: Hy MvanGeest 
the look of the BTN's are right and BTN 1 act right.
What the BTN's should do is when i click one of them the opend content should slideUp and when it's done the clickt content should slideDown.....

Comment: But why are the BTN's 2,3,4 next to each other? That completely destroys the sliding effect (in my opinion). They're inline too, so this isn't going to work... I don't think I understand which content goes where. Does BTN 2's content go into the same visible area as, say, BTN 1's?

Comment: No BTN 1 content pushes BTN 2, 3, and 4 down and there content taht all works actually pretty fine. But when i change the script so that the opend content slidesUp before the next content slidesDown It Only works for BTN 1 and 2.
and when i bring them into a list so that I can style them better(easier) nothing  works at all.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old entry but I thought I post my answer anyway. Might help someone.

There are couple of things that could be improved with your code. 
First since it looks like all of your classes are unique, I suggest using IDs because they are faster.

Point your lis to their respective content by linking to their hash like so

```
<nav>
    <li><a href="#Inhalt1">btn1</a></li>
</nav>
```

Then the JavaScript will hide your content and slideToggle the one you click

```
var content = ("#inhalt1, #inhalt2, #inhalt3");
   $(content).hide();
   $("nav a").click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $(content).hide();
   $($(this).attr("href")).slideToggle();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your script is not included in the jquery initialisation function. You should put all your script in:

```
$(function(){
// Put your code here
});
```

or

```
$(document).ready(function(){
// Put your code here
});
```

Comment: hy Shaoz

that's not the problem the script it self works but not the way i want it to...